# Why does my custom wordpress loop behave weird?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, loops, themes

I have made a custom theme, and some custom page templates. 
Two of the templates have the same loop. They both list the sub-pages of the parent page.
Somehow after 5 sub-pages the loop decides to make a mess and puts the last two sub-pages inside each other.

It breaks the footer and inserts code where it shouldn't.
The result of this can be seen @ http://spkow.com/sites/megatec/?page_id=16

I know I ain't the best coder as of yet.
What is going on?

```
<div id="parent_top_content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
<div id="parent_content_wrapper">
<?php
$pageChildren = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&hierarchical=0&child_of='.$post->ID);
if ( $pageChildren ) {
foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
echo '<a class="parent_list_link" href="'. get_permalink($pageChild->ID) .'"><div   class="parent_list_element"><div class="parent_list_thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail') . '</div><div class="parent_list_inner"><h3 class="parent_list_title">' . $pageChild->post_title.'</h3>';
if (!empty($pageChild->post_excerpt)){
echo '<p class="parent_list_excerpt">' . $pageChild->post_excerpt.'</p></div><span id="clear">&nbsp;</span></div></a>';
}
}
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening your link for all child pages, but you're only closing it if the child has an excerpt, resulting in invalid html.  See the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://spkow.com/sites/megatec/?page_id=16&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Try fixing that (and the other html errors) and see if that helps.

Comment: Great news; glad to help.  Of course, the problem will happen again if you have another post without an excerpt.  I think to fix the underlying problem, change your code so the `if` statement only closes the tags it opens (just the `<p>`), and close the rest (your `div`s and `a`) after the `if`.  It's the "Finish What You Start" principle mentioned in [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips); definitely worth a read if you want to become a better coder.